# Ошибка ant: antcontrib.properties - it could not be found

Tags: ant, android, java

Добрый день.

При сборке проекта Android ant'ом на Ubuntu появляется ошибка:

> Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.

Ошибка проявляется в строчке:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите кастомные таски Ant'а [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) и будет вам щастье

Comment: не лишним было бы добавить что ant-contrib продукт той-же конторы. но формально это лишь дополнение к анту, - third-party либа

Answer (score 1):

Итого.

Надо скачать `ant-contrib-version.jar` [отсюда](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/). Скопировать в папку ant (на Ubuntu это `/usr/share/ant/lib`) и подключить taskdef

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

И все будет ок.